# Including a javascript file with pandoc when going from markdown to html

Tags: javascript, html, command-line, include, pandoc

I am using pandoc to convert a markdown file to standalone html file. I have css file that I include with the `-c` command-line option. I would like to do the same thing with a javascript file, but I have not found an option to include script files similar to the `-c` option.

Is there such an option? If not, what is the most efficient way to do the inclusion?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `header-includes` [variable](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-set-automatically) in the YAML metadata header (and run `pandoc -s`):

```
---
header-includes: <script src="foo"></script>
---

my markdown document
```

Comment: the link points to the manual, not directly to the variable. Maybe they released the anchors in the help.

Comment: @Timo thanks, I updated the link to the section where it's been moved to...

Comment: how did you know that there is an anchor? My answer below also has a link, but the `https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#General-writer-options` url does not work properly because the anchor is not really correct.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector :-)

Answer (score 7):

More convenient could be to use the flag

```
`-H FILE, --include-in-header=FILE|URL`
```

as described [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) in the `pandoc` call. It implies `--standalone`.